# How to count number of scripts are use in a particular view using asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to count number of scripts tag use in a particular view in MVC?

Comment: for example: `$(document).find('script').length` (because you tagged jQuery). If you want a server side solution in asp.net you would need to parse the rendered document. You might need to consider dynamical added script tags thorugh 3rd party integrations

Comment: "as soon as possible". We are volunteers here. Your time is not more valuable than ours. Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest . If your request is really so urgent, then either hire a programmer or plan your work better. People here will respond as and when they feel able to. Also it's better if you show some effort yourself to investigate and solve the problem, then ask a question if your code attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

UI side solution

Try following script ,work fine

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script></script>
<script></script>
<script></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=  $("script").length;
alert(count)
});
</script>
```

You get 5 counts

Comment: Can I also get the completed script text also with count

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one also working  fine,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
var count=  document.getElementsByTagName('script').length;
alert(count)
});
</script>
```